# Translator Speech API Keys No Longer Show in Portal & Have Stopped Working

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have a free trial subscription to the Translator Speech API and recently I have been unable to view my Translator Speech keys in the Azure Portal. They've been replaced instead with an image of a dark cloud with one rain drop. I'm able to view my keys for my other service subscriptions so this issue seems to be isolated. I've also noticed that the key I was using previously is no longer working as I am now receiving  401 "Access Denied" Errors. It is my understanding that the free trial allows you to translate 2 hours of audio. I was using the service pretty rigorously so I would not be surprised if my free trial has expired but its status is still listed as active on Azure Portal. If anyone could give any insight that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

That error means that your Azure subscription (which is different than your F0 free tier Cognitive Services account) is not active.  Typically this happens if you have a 1 month Azure free trial subscription and the free 1 month period has expired, but it can also happen to paid Azure accounts if there is a problem with the billing such as an expired credit card.

You should be able to validate this in the subscription list in the Azure portal - https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade.

Comment: You are indeed correct. Thanks for the clarification!