# Can't Manage Access Keys for Cognitive Services Resource Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have had trouble managing my access keys for my Cognitive Services Resource on Azure. Every time I log in any browser and click on Manage Keys... the keys don't appear. Even if I click on the cloud icon, they only appear for a split second and then disappear. Has anyone else had this problem? How did they solve it?

[image]

Comment: I'm using Chrome and I've had no problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Translator Speech API Keys No Longer Show in Portal & Have Stopped Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43331635/translator-speech-api-keys-no-longer-show-in-portal-have-stopped-working/43331835#43331835):

That error means that your Azure subscription (which is different than your F0 free tier Cognitive Services account) is not active. Typically this happens if you have a 1 month Azure free trial subscription and the free 1 month period has expired, but it can also happen to paid Azure accounts if there is a problem with the billing such as an expired credit card.

You should be able to validate this in the subscription list in the Azure portal - https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Billing/SubscriptionsBlade.